# Como Fazer imprimir uma matriz no Windows Forms do visual Studio?

Tags: c#

Como posso fazer a impressão de uma matriz no windows Forms?
Eu tentei pelo listbox usando este código:

```
 public void Mostrar_Grafo(int Qtdlinha,int Qtdcoluna, string[,] MAdjacencia)
    {
        ListBox listbox1 = new ListBox();
        listbox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
        listbox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        this.Controls.Add(listbox1);
        listbox1.MultiColumn = true;
        listbox1.BeginUpdate();

        listbox1.Items.Add("Matriz de Adjacencia");
        listbox1.Items.Add("");

        for (int i = 0; i < Qtdlinha; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Qtdcoluna; j++)
            {
                listbox1.Items.Add(" " + MAdjacencia[i, j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Mas Fica mostrando os numeros de forma desorganizada como mostra na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu preciso que mostre em formato de matriz como este exemplo:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa montar a linha da matriz antes de adicioná-la ao listbox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Qtdlinha; i++)
{
    string linha = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < Qtdcoluna; j++)
    {
        linha += " " + MAdjacencia[i, j] + " ";
    }

    listbox1.Items.Add(linha);
}
```